# How to use docker build in next step of github actions after build step

Tags: docker, pytest, github-actions

following is the example GHA workflow yaml file I'm using. Currently I'm building an pushing docker image to artifact registry. And in the next step I run pytest on the docker image. But for next step it has to pull image which was build in the last step to run pytest. Is there any way I can run pytest without pulling the docker image from registry to save time.

```
      - name: Build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: my_registry:${{ github.run_number }}
          cache-from: |
            type=registry,ref=my_registry:cache
          cache-to: |
            type=registry,ref=my_registry:cache,mode=max
      - name: Pytest
        run: docker run my_registry:${{ github.run_number }} pytest
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [actions's example](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/share-image-jobs/) on how to share a docker image between jobs.

The action offers an [`outputs`¹](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images#inputs) argument:

> List of [output destinations](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#output) (format: `type=local,dest=path`).
>
> ¹ multiple `outputs` are [not yet supported](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1555)

You can use it to output your image to a tar file which you can load in the next step.

Example:

```
- name: Build
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: my_registry:${{ github.run_number }}
    cache-from: |
      type=registry,ref=my_registry:cache
    cache-to: |
      type=registry,ref=my_registry:cache,mode=max
    outputs: type=docker,dest=./myimage.tar
- name: Pytest
  run: |
    docker load --input ./myimage.tar
    docker run my_registry:${{ github.run_number }} pytest
```